# Math equations in latex with subscript

Tags: math-mode

Hello Im having problem with equation in latex:

```
\begin{equation}
Y_j(t) + \frac{\sum_\limits_{i\in B_j*} (Y_i(t + 1) - Y_i(t))}{M - |B_j*|}& j\notin B_j*\  \\

\end{equation}
```

for some reason (Y_i(t+1) ... is as subscript

I need my equation to look like in the picture
[image]

Comment: remove the empty lines for a start.

Comment: "lower index" meaning subscript

Comment: Remove the `_`.

Comment: I do not understand - what should I write or delete

Comment: The underscore `_` make the subscript.

Comment: \begin{equation}
Y_j(t) + \frac{\sum_\limits_{i\in B_j*}(Y_i(t + 1) - Y_i(t))}{M - |B_j*|}& j\notin B_j*\  
\end{equation}

Comment: still not like in the picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
Y_j(t) + \frac{\sum_{i\in B_{j^*}} (Y_i(t + 1) - Y_i(t))}{M - |B_{j^*}|}\quad j\notin B_{j^*}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]